# alert multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

i am submitting data through `FormData` and i am trying to alert values of check boxes which are checked in my form, right now i am able to make it work for only one check box.

how can i alert values of all those check boxes which are checked.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("update-form"));

$("#myCheckbox1").on('change',function(){
    if($("#myCheckbox1").is(':checked'))
        $('#hiddenInput1').val(1);
    else{
         $('#hiddenInput1').val(0);
    }
});
alert(
    $('#hiddenInput1').val()
);
```

**Check Box 1:**

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa" id="hiddenInput1">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox1">
```

**Example Check Box 2:**

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa1" id="hiddenInput2">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox2">
```

How to Alert Values of all check boxes which are checked in FormData without repeating code. i found similar example online but none were using FormData.

> Form Name is : update-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of start with attribute selector to select all checkboxes having id start with `myCheckbox` and attach it to change event handler.
Inside handler, you can read if checkbox is checked or not and change value of hidden input which is placed before checkbox.

See below code

```js
$(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox][id^=myCheckbox]").on('change',function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var $hiddenInput = $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]');
    if(isChecked)
        $hiddenInput.val(1);
    else{
         $hiddenInput.val(0);
    }
    alert($hiddenInput.val());
});

//iterate all hidden input on form submit
 $('#update-form').submit(function(){
    $('input[id^=hiddenUnput]').each(function(){
       alert($(this).val());
     });
    $(this).submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Exammple Check Box 1:
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa" id="hiddenInput1">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox1">
Example Check Box 2:
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa" id="hiddenInput2">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox2">
```

Comment: Thanks, how to achieve same alert result when clicked on submit button, instead of clicking on each checkbox.

Comment: You can iterate input hidden fields on submit of form. see my updated answer